# C# fill polygon (triangle)

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, draw

I have problem with draw two polygons.
I want to fill two triangles, but one is greater than the second.
I am using UserControl in winforms.
Code:

```
Point[] DOWN = new Point[] {new Point(0, 0), new Point(10, 0), new Point(5, 5)};
Point[] UP = new Point[] { new Point(0, 15), new Point(10, 15), new Point(5, 10) };

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(253, 198, 19));       
            e.Graphics.FillPolygon(brush, DOWN);
            e.Graphics.FillPolygon(brush, UP);
            brush.Dispose();
        }
```

[image: This is result of fill polygons]
Where is problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the PixelOffsetMode property:

```
e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(253, 198, 19))) {
  e.Graphics.FillPolygon(brush, DOWN);
  e.Graphics.FillPolygon(brush, UP);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the order counter-clockwise and start from the highest point:

```
new Point(5, 10), new Point(10, 15), new Point(0, 15)
```

Tell us if that helped. Sometimes those algorithms don't behave well on border conditions.

Comment: the problem persists :(